# How do I assign a default value if the user has not entered anything?

Tags: dart

I read that (??) assigns a value if the left part is null, if anyone can explain what null is, I would appreciate it.

stdout.write("Введите ваше имя: ");
final String userName = stdin.readLineSync() ?? "user";// как вот тут присвоить значение если пользователь ничего не ввел

print(userName);

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWMmy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stdin.readLineSync()` returns `null` if the user closes the input stream (such as by sending EOF).  If the user presses the Enter key without typing anything else, `stdin.readLineSync()` will return an *empty string* (`""`), not `null`.

You perhaps intend something like:

```dart
var userName = stdin.readLineSync();
if (userName == null || userName.isEmpty) {
  userName = "user";
}
```

You also might want to consider removing leading and trailing whitespace:

```dart
var userName = (stdin.readLineSync() ?? "").trim();
if (userName.isEmpty) {
  userName = "user";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See in Dart, `null` is a special value that means there's nothing there, uninitialised, like an empty cookie jar. You can have variables that start with null if you don't give it a real value. You can also check if something is null using `==`, and you can use `??` to pick a value if something might be null. So, null in Dart is like a placeholder for `nothing`.

and about `??`, it's called the null-aware operator. It's like a safety net for dealing with null values. If you have a variable that might be null, you can use `??` to provide a default value if it is null.

In your code snippet, you're askin' the user for their name. and you if don't type anything (`stdin.readLineSync()` gives us a `null`), So we set userName to `user` instead to deal with the null. So, it's like a backup name.

Update:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
    print("Enter your name: ");
    final String userName = stdin.readLineSync() ?? "user";
    print("Your name is $userName");
}
```

Comment: Well, this is understandable, but what about the example code that I showed?

Comment: if you do not enter anything in the console and press (enter / nothing), according to the idea, it should accept (user), but this does not happen



void main() {
  stdout.write("Введите ваше имя: ");
  final String userName = stdin.readLineSync() ?? "user";
  print(userName);
}

Comment: It's working perfectly fine for for me. `user` if you don't pass anything and press enter than user otherwise what you have entered. let me post the code in the answer too.

Comment: how can I send you a screenshot of mine? I ran your code, but when I just press enter, I see the result as (Your name is ) without user(

Comment: you can add it in your question by editing it. or else try this https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/LCg, execute it for default result, or add name in `Stdin Inputs`.

Comment: attached, please take a look)

Comment: i don't know how but the `stdin.readLineSync()` is not returning `null` in your case. Try the link i have putted in the previous comment it show the exact behaviour.